# Delete image when upload mutiple file in laravel is not working

Tags: javascript, html

i/m doing delete image when the client upload multiple image and preview that image. here is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input id="image" class="" name="image[]" type="file" multiple />
     <div class="preview clearfix">

    </div>
    <div class="upload-img">
         <label for="image">
               <u>Upload</u>
         </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is my JS to upload image and preview images

```
 $("#image").change(function(){

            var total_file = document.getElementById('image').files.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < total_file ; i++){
                var html = 
                "<div class='img pull-left'>"
                +"<img class='preview-img' data-id='"+i+"' id='preview-img-"+i+"' src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'>"
                +"<img class='delete-img' image-id='#preview-img-"+i+"' src='{{ url('/media/error.svg')}}'>"
                +'</div>';
                $('.preview').append(html);
            };
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.delete-img', function() {
            var img = $(this).attr('image-id');
            var id_img = $(img).attr('data-id');
            var total_files = document.getElementById('image').files;

            $(this).closest('.img').remove();
            delete total_files[id_img];

        });
```

my problem is delete image in UI but  do not delete element image. I want to delete both DOM HTML and file exist in

Comment: where is php or laravel in this question?

Comment: sr, i'm coding by framework laravel (

Comment: For now, you're not sending AJAX request pointing destroy method so that's because nothing happens on server.